# Conversion of rows into columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unique, jet-sql

I have this Project Class table which consists of Project ID,and there are 21 categories tagged to this Project ID and class codes.

[image]

The Project ID along with their class categories and class codes should be in one line (in the new table) when queried with the Project_ID and there shouldn't be any multiple instances.Something like this,

```
Project ID    Class_category1  Class_category2......So on
Value         Class_Code1      Class_Code 2........So on
```

How can I achieve this and using which function?

Comment: in sql (and excel, etc), there is a concept called "pivot" which converts rows to columns (and vice versa)

Comment: https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: Thanks Joe.I will try using that.

Comment: People here not expect screenshots instead you can portrait some sample data and expected Output to get better result

Answer (score 1):

You should use SQL **[PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)** syntax and may have to use [dynamic pivot](http://crispycrappy.blogspot.com/2013/12/dynamic-sql-pivot.html) if you don't have the list of all class_category data

Your query should be like below

```
select * 
from 
PA_PROJECT_CLASSES
pivot
(
    max(class_code) 
    for class_category in 
    (
    [254 codes],
    [330 codes],
    -- your categories in proper [] syntax
    )
)p
```